# How to enable autoscaling in Azure app service plan?

Tags: azure

In the pricing page for app service plan it states that standard, premium and isolated plans autoscaling is supported: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/

Is autoscaling happening automatically for these plans? 
Can I switch between plans (e.g. standard to premium and vice versa) at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is autoscaling happening automatically for these plans?

No, if you want to auto scale web app service plan from standard to premium, you need do it manually. This is typically referred to as Scale up or Scale down.

But, you can set parameters to have it automatically scale based on demand. This is typically referred to as Scale out or Scale in. More information about this please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-how-to-scale?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-web%2ftoc.json).

> Can I switch between plans (e.g. standard to premium and vice versa)
>   at any time?

Yes, you could do it on Azure Portal.

[image]

[image]

Note: It does not support change Consumption plan to App Service plan or change App Service plan to Consumption plan.